# Wireshark only capturing my packets, not packets on the network?

Tags: wireshark, packets

I just downloaded Wireshark on Windows 8.1, and when I try to capture packet it works just fine, just only for the current machine. I've "promiscuous mode" enabled, but nothing seems to happen? During the installation I installed WinPcap, and set it to run on boot. Is there any way to solve this? I've also tried to plug in a USB network adapter, without luck.

Comment: Typically due to a router. Routers isolate traffic between you and the router, whereas a switch may expose network traffic to you.

Comment: Is it possible to place a wireless switch in front of the router then?

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi network?  Promiscuous mode generally doesn't work on those, especially on Windows; you need monitor mode, but, unfortunately, WinPcap doesn't support that, so Wireshark doesn't support it, either.

Switched wired network?  Promiscuous mode [isn't enough on a switched network](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet); you need a "monitor port" or "SPAN port" or whatever the switch vendor calls it.